# Central limit theorem when the mean is not constant

Tags: distributions, central-limit-theorem

I've heard that there is a *soft* version or interpretation of the CLT that says —in summary— that it can be applied also to a sequence of independent real-valued random variables that share the same distribution *shape* but not the *mean* (for instance, a sequence of $n$ normal variables $X_i \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma)$ where $\mu_i$ can be different for each $i$).

Is that right? Where can I find it (textbook or article)?

And, a last one: In this case (where $X_i$ are independently and equally distributed except for their means), what would the distribution of $Y=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n{X_i}$ approximately be, according to CLT?

---

EDIT:

I want to stress that $X_i\sim N(\mu_i,\sigma)$ was just an example.

What I have is $X_i \sim F_i$, where $F_i$ stands for the CDF of $X_i$, and where all $F_i$'s are equal to the same distribution (with a known constant variance $\sigma^2$) except for the fact that they have different averages $\mu_i$.

---

EDIT:

Just to make it clearer, what I would like to know is whether or not it is correct to state this:

$Y=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n{X_i}$ is approximately distributed as $N(\mu_Y,\sigma_Y)$, where

- $\mu_Y$ can be estimated as $\bar{x} = \frac{x_1+ \cdots + x_n}{n}$ and
- $\sigma_Y$ can be estimated as $\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$, $s$ being the sample (quasi)standard deviation,

using a random sample $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ of $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$.

Comment: What do you know about $\mu_i$?

Comment: @Emre, that is a good question. All what we know about $\mu_i$ is that it is not constant. We can assume that there is a kind of *underlying central* $\mu$ which could be estimated as the average $\bar{x}=\frac{x_1+\dotsc+x_n}{n}$, where $x_i$ is an observation from $X_i$.

Comment: You don't need a CLT for independent normal variables; $X_1 + X_2 \sim N(\mu_1 + \mu_2, \sigma_1 ^2+ \sigma_2^2)$ and so on.

Comment: @Student001, see my edit above.

Comment: Google "Lindeberg Feller central limit theorem"

Comment: The distributions don't need to be the same shape.

Comment: See these Wikipedia links [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Lyapunov_CLT) [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Lindeberg_CLT)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A precise reference for the Lindeberg-Feller CLT is Theorem 4.12 in Foundations of Modern Probability by Olav Kallenberg.  I paraphrase it below:

> Let $(\xi_{n,j}; j = 1,\ldots,n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a triangular array
>   of row-wise independent random variables with mean $0$ and
>   $\sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}[\xi_{n,j}^2] \to 1$ *as $n\to\infty$*.
>
> Suppose that for any $\epsilon > 0$ we have 
>   $\sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}[\xi_{n,j}^2; |\xi_{n,j}|>\epsilon] \to 0$.  (*)
>
> Then $\sum_{j=1}^n \xi_{n,j} \overset{d}{\to} N(0,1)$.

Suppose the $X_i$ are arbitrary independent random variables. Let $\mu_j = \mathbb{E}[X_j]$ and $\sigma_j^2 = Var[X_j]$.

Take $\xi_{n,j} = \frac{X_j - \mu_j}{\sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^n \sigma_i^2}}$.  Then the theorem says
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^n \sigma_i^2}} \sum_{j = 1}^n (X_j - \mu_j) \overset{d}{\to} N(0,1),
$$
and thus
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{j=1}^n (X_j - \mu_j) \overset{d}{\to} N(0,\sigma^2)
$$
if the limit $\sigma^2 = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2 / n$ exists.  To put in another way, the sample mean $Y_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ satisfies
$$
\sqrt{n}(Y_n - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i)  \overset{d}{\to} N(0,\sigma^2),
$$
i.e. $Y_n$ has approximate distribution $N(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i, \sigma^2/n)$.  However, be warned that the theorem does not say exactly what the rate of convergence is!

I leave it as an exercise for you to see what the Lindeberg condition (*) is.

Comment: Therefore, just to be sure, does this mean that the distribution of $Y=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n{X_i}$ asymptotically tends to a normal distribution with mean $\mu=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n{E[X_i]}$ and standard deviation $\sigma= \frac{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n{Var[X_i]}}}{n} $? See also my last edit above, please.

Comment: Your $\mu$ and $\sigma$ here are not limiting values...  do you mean $\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[X_i]$? (assuming the limit exists, and similar for $\sigma$)

Comment: So, $\mu_Y = \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n{E[X_i]}}$ and $\sigma_Y = \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\frac{1}{n}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n{Var[X_i]}}}$ would be right, in case those limits exist. Isn't that?

Comment: And, about my last edition in the original question, could $\mu_Y$ and $\sigma_Y$ be approximated by $\bar{x}$ and $\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$ from a sample $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ of $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ ??

Comment: OK.  Just for a moment consider the simpler case that the $X_i$ are i.i.d.  Then what is the limit of $Y_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$? [Apologies if it seems I'm making you jump through hoops here, and I also fixed a minor typo in my answer with $\sqrt{n}$ scaling! :)]

Comment: Next consider the case that the variances are all equal, i.e. $\sigma_i = \sigma$ for every $i$.

Comment: I know what you mean... If $X_i$ are i.i.d. with $E[X_i]= \mu$ and $E[X_i]= \sigma^2$ , then for $Y_n=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n{X_i}$ it would be true that $E[Y_n]= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n{E[X_i]} = \mu$ and $Var[Y_n] = \cdots = \frac{1}{n}\sigma^2$...

Comment: yes, I know what you mean, but you also mentioned that "The random variables can have different distributions". In that case (the most general case, let us say), how would you estimate or approximate the mean and the standard deviation of $Y_n$ using a sample? I just want to be sure I am not wrong about my guesses...

Comment: So $Var[Y_n] = \sigma^2/n \to 0$ and $Y_n \to \mu$ by the LLN.  To get the fluctuations of $Y_n$ around $\mu$ you need $\sqrt{n}$ scaling, i.e. $\sqrt{n}(Y_n - \mu) \to N(0,\sigma^2)$.

Comment: In your last comment, would it be equivalent to say that $(Y_n-\mu) \rightarrow$ Normal with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$?

Comment: And therefore I am right... I can estimate or approximate the mean of $Y_n$ using $\bar{x}$ and can approximate the standard deviation of $Y_n$ using $\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$, from a sample $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ of $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$. Am I right???

Comment: More or less- see expanded answer.

Comment: thank you for your effort in answering my question and explaining me everything! As a final conclusion, although the convergence rate is unknown, I can apply Lindeberg-Feller CLT to state that ("more or less"), $\bar{x}$ and $s/\sqrt{n}$ are valid approximations for the mean and the standard deviation of $Y_n$, can't I?

Comment: A last comment/question:  In my concrete case, $n=15$ or so, and the $X_i$ variables are known to follow a Beta distribution, but are not i.i.d. I think I can apply this theorem. I don't know how to estimate an upper bound for the error for $n=15$. Also, I don't know if there is a better approximation for the concrete case of the sum of not i.i.d. Betas.

I can open a new question for this, if your think it is better.

Comment: I would like to draw your attention to the second part of the question, which can be found here:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157428/approximating-the-distribution-of-a-linear-combination-of-beta-distributed-indep